# Splitting string algorithm in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, substring

I'm trying to make the following algorithm work. What I want to do is split the given string into substrings consisting of either a series of numbers or an operator.

So for this string = "22+2", I would get an array in which [0]="22" [1]="+" and [2]="2".

This is what I have so far, but I get an index out of bounds exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "114+034556-2";
    int k,a,j;
    k=0;a=0;j=0;
    String[] subStrings= new String[string.length()];

    while(k<string.length()){
        a=k;
        while(((int)string.charAt(k))<=57&&((int)string.charAt(k))>=48){
            k++;}
        subStrings[j]=String.valueOf(string.subSequence(a,k-1)); //exception here

        j++;
        subStrings[j]=String.valueOf(string.charAt(k));
        j++;

   }}
```

I would rather be told what's wrong with my reasoning than be offered an alternative, but of course I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You want it to work for all operators, not just `+`, right?

Comment: Yes, for now the crtieria "Anything that is not a number" would be fine.

Comment: Are you interested in this particular algorithm, or the general problem of parsing numbers and operators?  That is, would you be interested in different algorithms?

Comment: I would, because I need to do this for a school project, but I'm also really interested in why what I'm doing is not working (I've looked at it over and over and I don't get it). Any input is very apprecciated in either case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm deliberately not answering this question directly, because it looks like you're trying to figure out a solution yourself.  I'm also assuming that you're purposefully not using the split or the indexOf functions, which would make this pretty trivial.

A few things I've noticed:

1. If your input string is long, you'd probably be better off working with a char array and stringbuilder, so you can avoid memory problems arising from immutable strings
2. Have you tried catching the exception, or printing out what the value of k is that causes your index out of bounds problem?
3. Have you thought through what happens when your string terminates?  For instance, have you run this through a debugger when the input string is "454" or something similarly trivial?

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm "purposefully" not using so much as I'm dumb and didn't know there were easier ways to do this, but yes, I would like to find out why this particular solution isn't working.

I took your suggestions regarding printing the index and I think I see what is happening now. It has to do, as you say, with what happens when it ends and the index keeps going because of the criteria I established. 

I'm still figuring it out, but thank you so much for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to split the numbers from the operators using [lookahead and lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
String equation = "22+2";
String[] tmp = equation.split("(?=[+\\-/])|(?<=[+\\-/])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your critera is simply "Anything that is not a number", then you can use some simple regex stuff if you dont mind working with parallel arrays -

```
String[] operands = string.split("\\D");\\split around anything that is NOT a number
char[] operators = string.replaceAll("\\d", "").toCharArray();\\replace all numbers with "" and turn into char array.
```

Comment: You need to escape your slashes.  Also, Character#isDigit seems more straightforward.

Comment: @Aurand Thanks, I always forget to double escape.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input="22+2-3*212/21+23";
     String number="";
     String op="";
     List<String> numbers=new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> operators=new ArrayList<String>();
     for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
         char c=input.charAt(i);
         if(i==input.length()-1){
             number+=String.valueOf(c);
             numbers.add(number);
         }else if(Character.isDigit(c)){
             number+=String.valueOf(c);
         }else{
              if(c=='+' || c=='-' || c=='*' ||c=='/'){
             op=String.valueOf(c);
             operators.add(op);
             numbers.add(number);
             op="";
             number="";
             }
         }
     }
     for(String x:numbers){
         System.out.println("number="+x+",");
     }
     for(String x:operators){
         System.out.println("operators="+x+",");
     }
```

this will be the output
number=22,number=2,number=3,number=212,number=21,number=23,operator=+,operator=-,operator=*,operator=/,operator=+,

Comment: Nope.  If `c` is a letter it will never be '+', '-', etc.

Comment: This works, and it provided some insight into what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @ermyuriel i'm glad that i can help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the general problem of parsing, then I'd recommend thinking about it on a character-by-character level, and moving through a finite state machine with each new character.  (Often you'll need a terminator character that cannot occur in the input--such as the \0 in C strings--but we can get around that.).

In this case, you might have the following states:

1. initial state
2. just parsed a number.
3. just parsed an operator.

The characters determine the transitions from state to state:

- You start in state 1.
- Numbers transition into state 2.
- Operators transition into state 3.

The current state can be tracked with something like an `enum`, changing the state after each character is consumed.

With that setup, then you just need to loop over the input string and switch on the current state.

```
// this is pseudocode -- does not compile.
List<String> parse(String inputString) {
    State state = INIT_STATE;
    String curr = "";
    List<String> subStrs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Char c : inputString) {
      State next;
      if (isAnumber(c)) {
        next = JUST_NUM;
      } else {
        next = JUST_OP;
      }

      if (state == next) {
        // no state change, just add to accumulator:
        acc = acc + c;
      } else {
        // state change, so save and reset the accumulator:
        subStrs.add(acc);
        acc = "";
      }
      // update the state
      state = next;
    }
    return subStrs;
}
```

With a structure like that, you can more easily add new features / constructs by adding new states and updating the behavior depending on the current state and incoming character.  For example, you could add a check to throw errors if letters appear in the string (and include offset locations, if you wanted to track that).